# In what cases would you use a rolling standard deviation instead of a regular standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

As the question say, I'm curious about this. I understand what standard deviation measures. But I would like to see cases where a rolling standard deviation should be used.

Comment: You use a rolling sddev when you expect the standard deviation to change over time. In this case, as long as the standard deviation is changing slowly enough, we should be able to see the change in the standard deviation over time if we use the right size window. Taking the SDDEV over an entire time series doesn't tell you if there was more volatility at one point than at another.

Answer (score 2):

I have a case regarding this matter. Basically, I have to calculate the standard deviation of every pixel of a set of images. So for the same pixel of every image, a set of data can be compiled and the standard deviation can be calculated. The problem is one image data is so big (aroud 20 MB) and there are thousands of images to be calculated. Without rolling standard deviation, I need to load all image data at once and then calculate the standard deviation per pixel, this will require a huge amount of RAM. Mind that I cannot load just one pixel of an image, and even if I could it would still be very inefficient because then, the number of times I need to load is N of image x N of pixel.

Using rolling standard deviation, you can just load only one image at once, and calculate the temporary standard deviation in every pixel. For every load of an image, the standard deviation can be updated until the final image you can have the final standard deviation of all pixels without needing a memory space of more than 20 MB.

I know the question is 1 year old, but I hope this helps you or anyone having the same question.

Comment: That's a good use case, +1.  But you don't need a rolling SD: your aim is to compute 20M SDs.  Thus, your job is simpler: just sum the images and sum their squares and use those at the end to compute the SDs.